Book on developing and implementing coupled field problem
Could some share a textbook that will help learn these particular aspects of this paper:
https://pmc.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/articles/PMC4159623/

Developing weak form
Consistent linearization
Getting stiffness matrix

I have taken classes on FEA as a mechanical engineer (but they were mostly focused of element development, solving structural and thermal problems). I like to learn the math followed in this paper. Thank you!
